# Is resource bundling needed on SPDY to reduce response times

Tags: cloudflare, spdy, http2

Here I use the term *bundling* to refer to concatenate JS and CSS resources together to reduce number of HTTP requests. HTTP/2 solves the underlying issues which gave the birth to resource bundling web development best practices in the first places (round trip times, resource fetch blocking). However, how much SPDY, which is now widely deployed, shares these characteristics with HTTP/2?

If I use SPDY-aware CDN, like CloudFlare, is there any sense to bundle resources anymore if I do not need to care about legacy clients?

Please note that resource transpiling might be done separately from bundling and this question is mainly about response times, not about compiling the code.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/2 (and its predecessor SPDY, which is now being phased out) clients can perform a larger number of concurrent requests to the server than HTTP/1.1 clients.

Where HTTP/1.1 could do between 4 and 8 concurrent requests at a time only, HTTP/2 can do typically up to 100.

The *bundling* of resources was basically a workaround to this HTTP/1.1 limitation, and it's not strictly needed anymore with HTTP/2.

The only reasons I could think of to continue bundling *may* be to increase gzip compression efficiency of resources (but this should be measured to quantify the benefits - and they could be really small if any at all) or for other application reasons.

If you don't care about legacy clients, in the typical case you can avoid bundling resources when using a HTTP/2 enabled CDN.

This should simplify the build of your web application (no need of a bundling phase anymore) without losses in response times, but the only way to be sure is to measure your specific case.